# Device (iPhone 5) Resolution not getting detected when working with Worklight 6.0.0.1

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, dojo, worklight-studio

I build one application using Worklight 6.0.0.1 and tested it on iPhone 4S. Its working fine. But when i tried testing it on iPhone 5 then screen size getting displayed according to iPhone 4S resolution i think. Its showing some vacant space above and below of the screen. Please refer snapshot for more detail.

[image]

I have tried changing the size of body in my css to

```
#content {
height: 568px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 320px;
```

}

But its not reflecting.

regards,
V@run

Comment: Which iOS version did both phones have?

Comment: Also make sure you are running the very latest fixes (there are more than 1 to download): http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039574

Comment: Simulator? Real device? Xcode 4 or 5? And if you have more of the HTML/CSS it could also help. The part I have a hard time to understand is how the status bar could be lower - I don't think a developer has access to this.

Comment: Are you Using a splash screen with 568px height ?

Comment: I'm using Xcode5 and on iOS7+4s its working fine, on iOS6+iPhone5 its looking as above and on Simulator+ iPhone retina 4inch its looking as above

Comment: Yes Nute! i'm using the latest fixpack Worklight 6.0.0.1

Comment: I have tested on iOS 6 + iPhone 4S, its also working fine on it.

Comment: Does it do the same with a blank WL application? What code changes have you done?

Comment: What about iOS 7 + iphone 5?

Comment: Hi Nute! Its working fine for blank WL application :-( What kind of changes you are asking about? I just made my own CSS file for App.

Comment: Please edit the question with your CSS. Can you also take the blank app with your CSS and see if it also happens? Start minimizing the CSS until you find the part that causes this phenomena. To simplify the work you can do these CSS modifications after opening the project in Xcode (navigate to the CSS, change, re-run).

Comment: You also mention Dojo, does it happen with a blank Worklight app that uses Dojo?

Comment: Hi Guys! I found out the strange problem but not able to resolve it. Its not related to CSS.This problem is occurring when i remove the default WL splash screen and add my own. I tested it two times by starting from scratch. I am also giving the right size to my splash screen. Working on it. If any of you have any idea please tell.

Comment: Problem Resolved!! i have replaced all the images in Eclipse itself by taking my all images with same name as taken by worklight by default. before i was replacing the images in Xcode. Only God knows the behavior of Worklight.

Comment: Please write the solution as answerto the question and mark as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem Resolved!! i have replaced all the images in Eclipse itself by taking my all images with same name as taken by worklight by default. before i was replacing the images in Xcode. Only God knows the behavior of Worklight.